# if statement to check if user is authorized based on email

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am pretty new to coding with Google Apps Script.

I am trying to make a function that will create a timestamp on a Google Sheet when the user clicks a button but only if the users email address is contained within a range on another sheet within the workbook.

For reference the tab which the user email addresses are listed is called "makers" and the list is within column A.

Currently the function is working where the users email address is in cell A2 of the list, however if it is anywhere else in the list (say A3) the script throws the error that I have coded.

Whenever the user is authorized (on the list) the code should stamp another tab with their email address and the date and time of their action.

Here is my code:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var usr = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var DateTime = new Date();
  var emails = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Makers").getRange("A2:A").getValues();


for (var i=0;i<emails.length;i++) {
  if (emails[i][0] === usr){
    ss.getRange('B3').setValue(usr);
    ss.getRange('C3').setValue(DateTime).setNumberFormat('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
    return;
  } else {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('You are not authorised to perform that action');
  throw new Error('You are not authorised to perform that action');
   }
 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (emails[i][0] === usr){ } else { throw new Error('You are not authorised')}
```

The `if`  statement here states that if the email, currently in the loop `emails[i][0]` is not `usr`, throw a new error. So,  it'll throw error, if the first email that is checked is not `usr`. Since you already have a `return` to end the function, when a match is found, you don't need a `else` statement.   Error should be thrown outside the loop:

```
for (var i=0;i<emails.length;i++) {
  if (emails[i][0] === usr){
    /*stuff*/
    return;
  }
 }//end for -loop
/*function not yet `return`ed. No email is matched. Time to Throw*/
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('You are not authorised to perform that action');
throw new Error('You are not authorised to perform that action');
```